# Android help in voice recognition!

Tags: android

Hey I need some help with an app.What I want is to record a sound(word...) from the MIC ,name it and save it to a list in two rows,one containing the name of the recording and the other the sound.
I'm new to android so if u can give me some code to start with,an example,anyting please.

Misu

Answer (score 2):

Erm, this question is really incredibly broad and the only way to answer it comprehensively is to write the code for you.  I suggest you google SQLite for your storage problem, and "android access mic" for recording them in the first place.

Comment: Agreed. One must crawl before walking... I'd recommend learning how to store some entered text to a simple list before jumping right into voice recording.